# ASP.NET Core, iframe and third party cookie related problem

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, cookies

I'm trying to load my local asp.net core web-app to another site using iframe but the data is loaded for a small time (1s), then all case cookie are deleted automatically, and iframe becomes blank.

Can someone tell me what the reason for this is, and how I can solve it?

I have tried:

- set x-frame-options to AllowAll
- and also set other header options

When I disable third-party cookies in my browser, it is prohibiting login operation.

Answer (score 1):

Add rewrite rule like below, and it works for me. It allow iframe use cookie, and won't delete cookie.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\WebApplication2.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile="\\?\%home%\LogFiles\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
      <rewrite>
          <outboundRules>
          <clear />
          <rule name="Add SameSite" preCondition="No SameSite">
              <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Set_Cookie" pattern=".*" negate="false" />
              <action type="Rewrite" value="{R:0}; SameSite=None;Secure=true" />
          </rule>
          <preConditions>
              <preCondition name="No SameSite">
                  <add input="{RESPONSE_Set_Cookie}" pattern="." />
                  <add input="{RESPONSE_Set_Cookie}" pattern="; SameSite=None;Secure=true" negate="true" />
              </preCondition>
          </preConditions>
          </outboundRules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: 1940793d-c348-4b1b-93be-83b6228fd09b-->
```

[image]

[image]